# How to post a c# object to an action from a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a view which is rendered by calling an action and I'm passing a view model to it e.g. Vm1 then populating some drop down lists.

On this view, I have a "Filters" section with some text boxes and a "Filter" button and I'd like to call another action passing the values of the text boxes and then rendering the second view partially on the page within a div.

So I have done this and my action looks like below which is called by ajax when the "Filter" button is clicked:

```
ActionResult ActionName (string inputText1, string inputText2, string inputText3, ...)
```

Because I have about 10 text boxes, I'd like to create a new c# object and passing that object to this action to look like this which is simpler:

```
ActionResult ActionName(MyActionFilters myFilters)
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can have a model as below

```
public class MyActionFilters
{
  public string Property1{get;set;}
  public string Property2{get;set;} 
  public string[] Property3{get;set;} 

  // add any number of properties....
}
```

you can pass the empty model in Get Action method

```
ActionResult ActionName()
{
  MyActionFilters myEmptyActionFilers= new MyActionFilters();
  View(myEmptyActionFilers)
}
```

in the form

```
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property1)
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property2)
```

then in the post method you can access the model that is populated in the form
I have removed the previous code. the new code is after the Edit Tag :)

Edit:
Sorry I was not around. This kind of functionality can be achieved easily using AJAX :)

It goes as below.

```
[HttpPost]
PartialViewResult ActionName(MyActionFilters myActionFilers)// this is magic
{
  /*you can access the properties here like myActionFilers.Property1 and pass the 
    same object after any manipulation. Or if you decided have a model which contains 
    a variable to hold the search results as well. That is good.*/

   return PartialView(myActionFilers);
}
```

So far [this](http://mvc3only.blogspot.com/2012/04/aspnet-mvc3-ajax-form-submission-simple.html) is a good example to refer.

And do not forget to add `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script reference to your view. If not Ajax will not affect.In the given example he has done it in the _Layout as you can see.

PS: Choose properties of models that is going to be passed to views, wisely and Enjoy Ajax!!

Comment: thanks. I don't like to change the page, could these be PartialViews and being loaded into a div on the page?

Comment: So I should be creating one separate partial view containing both search filters and search result or one partial view for each?

Comment: search filters will be always there and search results will be loaded to as a partial view. See my update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the form input names to the properties of your ViewModel, then MVC will do some magic to make  For example:

```
public class FormViewModel {
    public string input1 {get;set;}
    public string input2 {get;set;}
    // and so on
}
```

then on your Action:

```
public ActionResult FormPost(FormViewModel model) {
    // you'll have access to model.input1, model.input2, etc
}
```

Lastly, for example, on your HTML Form you'll want to create:

```
<input type="text" name="input1" />
<input type="text" name="input2" />
```

or you could use `Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Input1)` and the helper will name everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The name property of your input tags, should be prefixed by the object name ("MyActionFilters")

for example:

```
<input type="text" name="MyActionFilters.YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME" />
```

btw, your action method should be annotated with HttpPost attribute.

[HttpPost]
ActionResult ActionName(MyActionFilters myFilters)

Comment: Could an HttpPost return a PartialView? Could a Post happen by ajax?

Comment: Sure! You can do a post using JQuery: $.ajax({type: "POST", url: url, data: data, success: function(data) { $('#someelement').html(data); }, dataType: dataType}); and return a view that is HTML, and will be added on your page. To do the post request check this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/